# How is the Chain rule used to show that $\int_t^{t+\tau} f(x(t))\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \ dt=\int_{x(t)}^{x(t+\tau)} f(x) \ dx$?

Tags: calculus

**Question**

How is the Chain rule used to show that $$\int_t^{t+\tau} f(x(t))\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \ dt=\int_{x(t)}^{x(t+\tau)} f(x) \ dx$$

**Attempt**

I recognize that

$$\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t))=f(x(t))\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \ dt,$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.  In the integral above, I attempted the substitution $u=x(t)$. Then $du=\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \ dt$,  $t=x^{-1}(u)$ and $t+\tau=x^{-1}(u)+\tau$. So we should have:

$$\int_t^{t+\tau} f(x(t))\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \ dt=\int_{x^{-1}(t)}^{x^{-1}(t)+\tau} f(u) \ du.$$
However, this is not the same as the desired integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we have to realize that originally the limits of integration are in terms of the dummy variable $t$.  So, in order to shift the limits of integration onto the variable $u$, we must find a upper limit $u_2$ so that $u_2=x(t+\tau)$ (where we have simply plugged the upper limit (in terms of the dummy variable $t$) into the defining relationship for $u$).  We find the lower limit similarly.

For example, let's evaluate $$I=\int_3^5 2xe^{x^2} \,d x.$$  We make the $u$-substitution $$u=x^2,$$ to find that $$I=\int_9^{25} e^u \,d u.$$  Note how we found the limits of integration in terms of $u$: we just plugged the limit of integration in terms of $x$ into the defining relation for $u$, as described above.

Comment: The example made everything make sense. I can't believe I was caught up on this!